# Covering Up Some Old Wall Art

Tags: painting, paint, repainting, wallpaper, paint-removal

We've got some wall art painted on to our walls with a paint brush that we'd like to cover up, but we'd like to be able to cover it up in a way that won't ruin the integrity of it, so that if anyone wants it back in the  future, we can still have it there. That means painting over it isn't an option.

Are there any ways to wallpaper it such that the wallpaper will sit on top of the art and can be taken down at some point in the future?

Thanks.

Comment: Might consider a tapestry.

Comment: I understand your sentiment, and I've felt similarly about some walls in my late grandmother's house, but I'm not sure about how effective such a thing would be from a preservation standpoint.  If the wall is interior, the back is accessible and replaceable, and you're serious about preserving the artwork, I would think cutting apart the old wall, (use a temporary wall if the original was load-bearing), removing the artwork, and then rebuilding the wall might be easier and more useful than trying to build a usable false wall in front of it.

Comment: spray the wallpaper back with post-it glue.

Answer (score 6):

I would put a wood frame around/over it then cover the frame with a hardboard then decorate that.

Many times that an internal framed wall has been removed to find things behind.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Solar Mike](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/97780/solar-mike) mentioned, you can try [something like this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/47-75-in-x-7-98-ft-Smooth-Brown-Hardboard-Wall-Panel/3014304).  You would put this up, perhaps make an accent wall if you wanted - [here's an example](https://www.normandyremodeling.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Bgie_AFTER_3-2.jpg), but there are so many variations you can do, totally up to your creativity.  Or keep it very basic and frame outside.  Although, with 4x8 sheets you would probably need something in between, some sort of vertical stile, even lets say a 1x2 piece to cover the gaps - as it's somewhat tough to join these and get a finished look over lets say a 8-16 foot long wall.